# Unable to install SVN connector in eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, javahl

I was able to install SVN Team Provider. However, I am unable to install SVN Team Connector for Eclipse Oxygen (using 64bit version).

When SVN Team Provider is available and I navigate to "SVN Repository Exploring", it is supposed to automatically display a panel to install appropriate SVN Connector. But, I am not getting any such window.

I am getting the following error message,

```
SVN: '0x0040010b: Obtain Project Name' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolved**

I was able to resolve this issue by following these steps in eclipse,

1. Navigate to Help >> Install New Software...
2. Use the following URL, http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/
3. When you expand the groups, you will not see Win64 JavaHL binaries. Try unchecking the check box "Group items by category". You wil not see Win64 JavaHL binaries in the list.
4. Select the Win64 JavaHL Binanries and click on next to install.
5. Restart eclipse

You should be good to go now.

*Credits to Michele Mariotti* (Refer link below, comment #22)
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518033#c22